# Creating a dataset from 2d matrices

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataset, training-data

I have a series of 2d matrices like these two:

```
matrix_1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
matrix_2 = np.array([[10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18]])
```

And Each matrix has a label like:

```
labels = np.array([0, 1])
```

I want to make a dataset from these matrices to train my ML model later.
First I tried to make small .csv files for each matrix but we cannot train an ML model on multiple .csv files.

Then, I tried this code:

```
matrix_1_flat = matrix_1.flatten()
matrix_2_flat = matrix_2.flatten()

dataset = np.array([matrix_1_flat, matrix_2_flat])
dataset = np.transpose(dataset_1)
```

But I feel like that spatial information will be lost. Is there any other function apart from those I'm using to create what I want?

Actually by labels, I mean y variables in machine learning terms. In this example, matrix_1 and matrix_2 (two 2d matrices) are my x_train and the label of matrix_1 is 0 (or even cat if it makes it easier to understand) and the label of matrix_2 is 1 (or dog).

I want the train and its labels to be like this:

```
x_train = np.array([[[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]],[[10, 11, 12],[13, 14, 15],[16, 17, 18]]])  
y_train = y = np.array(["cat", "dog"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to make a dataset such that each x-y pair (a matrix, and a label) have x in its original shape (to not loose spatial information, treating each matrix as image-like).

With the aid of `numpy`, you can create a compressed file representing the dataset as follows:

```py
matrix_1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
matrix_2 = np.array([[10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18]])

# preparing "x" and "y" - the dataset
matrices = [matrix_1, matrix_2]
labels = np.array([0, 1])

# save into an npz object: 
#  - it's dict-like, so we use "x" and "y" as keys
#  - this will be saved as "matrix_dataset.npz"
np.savez_compressed('matrix_dataset', x=matrices, y=labels)
```

The `npz` file can be later loaded into memory:

```py
ds = np.load('matrix_dataset.npz')
```

You can access the "x" and "y" fields simply by their key:

```py
# e.g. if you want to train your model, after loading
x_train = np.array(ds['x'])
y_train = np.array(ds['y'])

# your model fitting code...
```

Note that the shape of `x_train` is now `(N, 3, 3)` where `N` (in this case is 2) refers to the batch axis, so doing `x_train[0]` will retrieve the first 3x3 matrix.

Comment: Excuse me for returning to this question, but when we have multiple matrices, how can we manage to create matrices = [matrix_1, matrix_2] for not entering every element manually, please?

Comment: Can you provide more details about how these matrices came from? I mean are they stored in some set of files, or collection?

Comment: Actually, I have a function that takes in a person's data and spits out a matrix. 
As I have a lot of persons to extract their data, I would have several matrices (maybe thousands) and I need to put these matrices together to create a DB. I'd like to do as you told me to create a npz DB, but I don't know how to do it for many matrices.

Comment: The easy solution would be to define two lists, i.e. `matrices = []` and `labels = []`, then loop over each person to get a matrix `m` and a label `y`. Inside the loop you append both matrix and label, i.e. `matrices.append(m)` and `labels.append(y)`. Once the loop is over you create the npz file, e.g. `np.savez_compressed('matrix_dataset', x=matrices, y=labels)`. One issue with such solution is that if there are too many matrices (say millions or more) you could run out of memory. Does this help?

Comment: I'm going to test this solution. I don't know if it's going to run out of memory. Anyway, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not that clear. What is your x and y variables for training? And what do you mean with labeling? If you mean that the labels are the y variables than a simple machine learning could be:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

x_train = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
y_train = np.array([0, 1, 0])  # Labels for x_train
x_test = np.array([[10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18]])

model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(x_train, y_train)
predictions = model.predict(x_test)
```

In this case we use x_train and y_train to train the model. Hence 7,8,9 will result in the label 0. Therefore this would not be a good training set for the test set as above. Since these values are not represented in the trainingset. But as the 7,8,9 values the closest to the test set, we get the labels: 0

```
print(predictions)
[0 0 0]
```

If this is not what you mean than you need to be more specific in your question

Comment: I add some details in my Edit part, I hope it makes my question a bit more clear. Anyway, thanks for your answer even though it's not actually what I'm looking for.

Comment: I am afraid it is still not clear to me. Why are you adding 3 lists in a array and later flatten it? Is that how you retrieve the data, or has that any meaning, (if so you might want to keep it). So:

x_train = np.vstack([matrix_1, matrix_2])
y_train = np.array(['cat', 'cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog', 'dog'])

Otherwise:
matrix_1 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
matrix_2 = np.array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18])
x_train = np.vstack([matrix_1, matrix_2])
y_train = np.array(['cat', 'dog'])

And than:
model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(x_train, y_train)

Comment: Even though @luca Anzalone's answer was what I wanted, I edited my question again, to make it more clear for you and for future reference. I appreciate your help very much!